# Horizontal bar chart in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

When Googling "horizontal gnuplot bar chart", the first result I could find [http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/histogram.html](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/%7Ezov1/gnuplot/html/histogram.html) suggests rotating (!) the final bar chart which seems rather baroque. Nonetheless I tried the approach but the labels are cut off.

[image: first attempt at a horizontal bar chart in gnuplot 5.2]

```
reset
$heights << EOD
dad                     181
mom                     170
son                     100
daughter        60
EOD

set yrange [0:*]      # start at zero, find max from the data
set boxwidth 0.5      # use a fixed width for boxes
unset key             # turn off all titles
set style fill solid  # solid color boxes

set colors podo

set xtic rotate by 90 scale 0
unset ytics
set y2tics rotate by 90

plot '$heights' using 0:2:($0+1):xtic(1) with boxes lc variable
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I would use `boxxyerrorbars` plotting style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can solve the code of a rotated histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021100/how-can-solve-the-code-of-a-rotated-histogram)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link you are referring to is from approx. 2009. gnuplot has developed since then. As @Christoph suggested, check `help boxxyerror`.

**Script:** (*edit*: shortened by using 4-columns syntax for `boxxyerror`, i.e. `x:y:+/-dx:+/-dy`)

```
### horizontal bar graph
reset session

$Data << EOD
dad         181
mom         170
son         100
daughter     60
EOD

set yrange [0:*]      # start at zero, find max from the data
set style fill solid  # solid color boxes
unset key             # turn off all titles

myBoxWidth = 0.8
set offsets 0,0,0.5-myBoxWidth/2.,0.5

plot $Data using (0.5*$2):0:(0.5*$2):(myBoxWidth/2.):($0+1):ytic(1) with boxxy lc var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

> what does
> `2:0:(0):2:($0-myBoxWidth/2.):($0+myBoxWidth/2.):($0+1):ytic(1)` mean?

Well, it looks more complicated than it is. Check `help boxxyerror`. From the manual:

> 6 columns: `x  y  xlow  xhigh  ylow  yhigh`

So, altogether:

1. x take value from column 2, but not so relevant here since we will use the xyerror box
2. y take pseudocolumn `0` which is line number starting from zero, check `help pseudocolumns`, but not so relevant here as well
3. xlow `(0)` means fixed value of zero
4. xhigh value from column 2
5. ylow `($0-myBoxWidth/2.)`, line number minus half of the boxwidth
6. yhigh `($0+myBoxWidth/2.)`, line number plus half of the boxwidth
7. `($0+1)` together with `... lc var`:  color depending on line number starting from 1
8. `ytic(1)`: column 1 as ytic label

For some reason (which I don't know) gnuplot still doesn't seem to have a convenient horizontal histogram plotting style, but at least it offers this `boxxyerror` workaround.

Comment: whoa... what does `2:0:(0):2:($0-myBoxWidth/2.):($0+myBoxWidth/2.):($0+1):ytic(1)` mean?